# android delete app data strange issue

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to clear all data of my application from internal storage and the problem is that it's working on emulator. I can delete all files,setting all shared preferences to default and deleting database, but when I run i on my phone (HTC EVO 3D) after I reset the App, the images which I receive from web server are not comming..and the only way which that can be happen is if I already have them in my database...which is really strange because I've already delete the database and all other files. Here is the code which I'm using :

```
        //Delete sqlite files : 
        boolean dbFile = deleteDatabase("stampii_sys_tpl.sqlite");
        Log.e("","deleted : "+dbFile);

        String cache = this.getCacheDir().toString();
        Log.e("","dbPath : "+cache);
        File ChFolder = new File(cache);
        boolean cachee = deleteDirectory(ChFolder);
        Log.e("","Database Folder Delete Success : "+cachee);


        // Delete Databases Folder :
        String dbPath = "/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/";
        Log.e("","dbPath : "+dbPath);
        File dbFolder = new File(dbPath);
        boolean dbFold = deleteDirectory(dbFolder);
        Log.e("","Database Folder Delete Success : "+dbFold);

        // Delete Files Folder :
        String name = this.getFilesDir().toString();
        Log.e("","path : "+name);
        File files = new File(name);
        boolean filesFol = deleteDirectory(files);
        Log.e("","filesFol : "+filesFol);

        // Clear Shared Preferences : 
        editor.putBoolean("resetApp", false);
        editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
        editor.putInt("storagePath", 0);
        editor.putInt("lastUser", 0);
        editor.putBoolean("getInfoFromJsonForColl", true);
        editor.commit();


static public boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if( path.exists() ) {
      File[] files = path.listFiles();
      if (files == null) {
          return true;
      }
      for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
         if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
           deleteDirectory(files[i]);
         }
         else {
           files[i].delete();
         }
      }
    }
    return( path.delete() );
  }
```

So my question is...Am I doing something wrong and if there is a possibility of Android to keep somehow a database of the application in cache or something like that..even if the original file is deleted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting your database file why don't you just delete the data in your tables. In this case you won't need to copy paste or create your database again. Just clear the data that you don't need anymore and that should fix your problem! : )